# How to call a slot with arguments when a dialog is accepted?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialogButtonBox:

```
QDialogButtonBox buttonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel, Qt::Horizontal, &dialog);
```

And when user presses the `Ok` button I want to call a slot, which has 2 `QString` arguments. I was trying to use signals, but I cannot make it work.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
 connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, this, 
        App::replace);
```

`App::replace` is the slot I want to call, but I do not know how to pass the arguments.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you "couldn't make it work", please include the details of what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a slot and in that slot call your requested function like this.

```
...
connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));
...

//slot implementation
void CLASS::accept()
{
    foo(QString1, QString2);
}
```

Something similar to this. In your particular case it will be like following

```
...
connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));
...

//slot implementation
void App::accept()
{
    replace(QString1, QString2);
}
```

The reason is that slot can accept less or equal arguments that signal provides. In this case signal `accepted` doesn't provide any arguments so you can't get any arguments. For that you have to manually collect and pass them in your slot.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [@Arsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53030676/2610810), you can `connect` a lambda that provides the requisite arguments

```
connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, this, [this](){ replace(value1, value2); });
```