# Calling a function with arguments when a QPushButton is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I want to call a function `function(QPushButton button)` when the user clicks a button. 
I tried `connect(myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(myFunction(myClass)));` but it does not work. I could do a separate function for slot but i need to create connections dynamicly for buttons created by user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt 5 assign slot with parameters to a QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150890/qt-5-assign-slot-with-parameters-to-a-qpushbutton)

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov QSignalMapper is deprected.

Comment: These days the best option is usually a lambda capturing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. @Rinat Veliakhmedov told me to check [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150890/qt-5-assign-slot-with-parameters-to-a-qpushbutton), but QSignalMapper is deprected and does not work with custom objects. I searched for a replacement for this method and found [that theard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399947/replacing-deprecated-qtsignalmapper-class-to-forward-signals-in-qt5). Solution with `emit myFunction(myClass)` is perfect for my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the button using `sender()` function. This function is used to get the senders in slots. Then you have to cast it to a class (in this case `QPushButton`) to be able to use it. If there is a need to pass another argument, please check out the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030556/how-to-call-a-slot-with-arguments-when-a-dialog-is-accepted/53030676#53030676) question.

Comment: @BeetMacol Then please check out the Q&A I menitioned